# Merge into a nested object using mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB collection with a document structure similar to:

```
{
    "_id" : "xxx",
    "inner : {
        "foo" : 1,
        "bar" : 2
    }
}
```

Database version is **4.2.6**

and an aggregation pipeline whose penultimate stage is `$project` with an outcome document matching something like this one:

```
{
    "_id" : "xxx",
    "inner : {
        "baz" : 3
    }
}
```

Followed by a final stage to merge into the collection:

```
{
    "$merge" : {
        into: "myCollection",
        on: "_id",
        whenMatched: "merge",
        whenNotMatched: "discard"
    }
}
```

However as a result, the existing `inner` document fields are overridden by the `$merge` results. Meaning:

Expected results:

```
{
    "_id" : "xxx",
    "inner : {
        "foo" : 1,
        "bar" : 2,
        "baz" : 3
    }
}
```

Actual results:

```
{
    "_id" : "xxx",
    "inner : {
        "baz" : 3
    }
}
```

How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "merge" option merges the root document, so `inner` field is replaced in your query.
Try to replace the merge with this merge that uses pipeline.
I haven't tested it but i think it will be ok.
`$$new` variable is mongo-defined to refer to the document coming from pipeline.

```
{
    "$merge" : {
        into: "myCollection",
        on: "_id",
        whenMatched: 
          [{"$project": 
             {"_id": "$_id",
              "inner": {"$mergeObjects": ["$inner","$$new.inner"]}}}],
        whenNotMatched: "discard"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer was a good lead, although the `$project` pipeline caused every field except for `_id` and `inner` to be overridden. This is not what I had wanted of course.

What should have been the obvious choice, was simply to use `$addFields` instead:

```
 whenMatched:  [
     {"$addFields" :
         {"inner.baz": "$$new.baz"}
     }
 ]
```